# Accessing images from grails in-line plugin when deployed in a tomcat server

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have two grails applications and created an inline plugin named *cmcore*. I placed some images in `cmcore/web-app/images` so that both of my applications have access on the said images. Images are successfully accessed by both applications in development environment but whenever I build WAR files of my applications in test environment and deploy it in a tomcat server, the images in *cmcore* becomes not accessible resulting to a resource not found error.

I extracted the generated WAR file and found out that the images from my inline plugin are not present in the `images` directory of the extracted WAR file, instead I found it in `plugins/cmcore-0.1/images`.

I've already tried the code below to do the job but it still didn't work.

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'logo.jpg')}" height="30" width="30">
```

How can the application access those images whenever packaged in a WAR file and deployed in a server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to get acces to images in 'plugin'? Try this:

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'logo.jpg', plugin: 'cmcore')}" height="30" width="30">
```